# Disable npm "Warning - tslint: error no-string-literal: object access via string literals is disallowed"

Tags: npm, warnings

How do i disable npm warning "tslint: error no-string-literal: object access via string literals is disallowed" I tried adding the rule "no-string-literal": false in tslint.json. I still see the warning.

Answer (score 1):

In tslint config file, under `rules`, set `"no-string-literal"` to `false` so it becomes: `"no-string-literal": false`

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-string-literal/

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line **"no-string-literal": false** in your tslint.json

```
{
    "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": [
            "config/**/*.js",
            "node_modules/**/*.ts",
            "coverage/lcov-report/*.js"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-console": false,
        "jsx-no-lambda": false,
        "no-string-literal": false    
    }
}
```